# I need to add a new tag to all odoo customers

Tags: odoo

I have 4069 customers in my odoo 8.0 software and all of them need the tag "new".
How can i add to all customer the TAG = new ?
Can i make it with xmlrpc or with a module ?

I try to make it with xlmrpc python but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `mass_editing` module (https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/mass_editing/), it works flawlessly for cases like this. I actually used it a while ago to modify the tag for several hundred customers with just a few clicks.

It has many other uses, give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want using simple SQL statements. First you need to check the ID for the `new` category:

```
SELECT id FROM res_partner_category where name='new'
```

Assuming the `new` category has an ID of `10`, the next thing to do is insert all your `category-partner` relations:

```
INSERT INTO res_partner_res_partner_category_rel (category_id, partner_id)
SELECT 10 as category_id, id as partner_id
FROM res_partner
WHERE customer=true
```

You're done!

Comment: and when I want to Delete all the new Tag from all Companys? Can you give me another example ?